# Create an arrow in Krita

Tags: vector, krita, arrow

I would like to create an arrow in Krita.

How could I create an arrow (if possible vectorized) in Krita?

Answer (score 7):

First, create a vector layer:

[image]

Then, draw a line (you can use shift to help to obtain a true horizontal line):

[image]

Then, select the mouse tool, and click on the line to select it:

[image]

You have then access to the tool settings on the right. Select the `Line` tab, and select the arrow head you want in the line style part.

[image]

You have access to 3 different arrow sizes. You can also change the width of the line (which also changes the size of the arrow), round the tip of the arrow, dash the line and put a two-side arrow using the different options. Moreover, following the same process with the Bezier Curve tool, you can also create curved arrows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :)